# Changing stroke color of svg via CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have graphics on my page with embedded svg files.

```
<object id="inspektion-svg" data="images/SVG/Inspektion.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
   <!---Fallback--->
   <!-- Your Browser cannot show svg. -->
</object>
```

The SVG files look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96.885" height="74.674" viewBox="0 0 96.885 74.674">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #c2d9ef;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }

      .cls-1 {
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        stroke-linejoin: round;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Gruppe_40" data-name="Gruppe 40" transform="translate(-367 -53)">
    <path id="Pfad_76" data-name="Pfad 76" class="cls-1" d="M455.808,65v50.481H371V65" transform="translate(2.038 10.192)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_77" data-name="Pfad 77" class="cls-1" d="M400,63.077V55h18.173v8.077" transform="translate(31.597)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_78" data-name="Pfad 78" class="cls-1" d="M376,63.077V55h18.173v8.077" transform="translate(7.135)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_79" data-name="Pfad 79" class="cls-1" d="M381.115,71.115H369V59h92.885V71.115H449.77" transform="translate(0 4.077)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_80" data-name="Pfad 80" class="cls-2" d="M401.472,82.246,405.494,62.8,383.333,91.876l13.5-1.676-4.022,19.442L414.969,80.57Z" transform="translate(14.608 7.954)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now I want to change the stroke color subsequently via CSS.

If I create a CSS class like:

```
.darkstroke {
  stroke: #7ca7d7;
}
```

And assign it to the object, nothing changes. Also, when I modify the svg and remove all `<style>` attributes does not help.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a higher qualifier in the css in order to override the inline css from the svg. So simply by adding an additional qualifier the css in the css file now outranks the one in the svg.

```css
svg .cls-1{
   stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96.885" height="74.674" viewBox="0 0 96.885 74.674">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #c2d9ef;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }

      .cls-1 {
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        stroke-linejoin: round;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Gruppe_40" data-name="Gruppe 40" transform="translate(-367 -53)">
    <path id="Pfad_76" data-name="Pfad 76" class="cls-1" d="M455.808,65v50.481H371V65" transform="translate(2.038 10.192)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_77" data-name="Pfad 77" class="cls-1" d="M400,63.077V55h18.173v8.077" transform="translate(31.597)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_78" data-name="Pfad 78" class="cls-1" d="M376,63.077V55h18.173v8.077" transform="translate(7.135)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_79" data-name="Pfad 79" class="cls-1" d="M381.115,71.115H369V59h92.885V71.115H449.77" transform="translate(0 4.077)"/>
    <path id="Pfad_80" data-name="Pfad 80" class="cls-2" d="M401.472,82.246,405.494,62.8,383.333,91.876l13.5-1.676-4.022,19.442L414.969,80.57Z" transform="translate(14.608 7.954)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.darkstroke` isn't an element inside your `svg`. To interact with the SVG you need to apply the stroke to something inside the SVG (usually a `<path>`).

So something like this:

```
#Pfad_76 {
  stroke: blue;
}
```

However, there are several issues with using external styles and an svg embedded using `<object>`. Basically, you need to define your styles **inside** the svg. If you want to use an external style sheet you need to have this (change paths) INSIDE the svg file.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
<svg>...</svg>
```

That said, typically your best bet if you need to modify the SVG later is to simply place the SVG code into the HTML without using the embed object.